# Bash if statement

Tags: bash, shell

As everybody knows the simple `if` statement is like so:

> if TEST-COMMANDS; then CONSEQUENT-COMMANDS; fi

Then the doc says:

> The TEST-COMMAND list is executed, and if its return status is zero,
>   the CONSEQUENT-COMMANDS list is executed

Does it mean that the return status of the TEST-COMMAND is converted to boolean true/false using the the rule:

> return status - 0 -> true
>   return status - 1 -> false

and then used by if statement to determine what action to take?

Comment: That's exactly what it means: where's the difficulty?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. For example:

```
$ exitwith() { return $1; }
$ for stat in {0..10}; do
> if exitwith $stat; then
> echo "An exit status of $stat is considered true"
> else
> echo "An exit status of $stat is considered false"
> fi
> done
An exit status of 0 is considered true
An exit status of 1 is considered false
An exit status of 2 is considered false
An exit status of 3 is considered false
An exit status of 4 is considered false
An exit status of 5 is considered false
An exit status of 6 is considered false
An exit status of 7 is considered false
An exit status of 8 is considered false
An exit status of 9 is considered false
An exit status of 10 is considered false
```

But it's actually a little more complicated than that, because the exit status is a 8-bit unsigned integer, it can only range from 0 to 255; values outside that range get reduced modulo 256 into that range:

```
$ for stat in -2 -1 255 256 257; do
> if exitwith $stat; then
> echo "An exit status of $stat (actually $?) is considered true"
> else
> echo "An exit status of $stat (actually $?) is considered false"
> fi
> done
An exit status of -2 (actually 254) is considered false
An exit status of -1 (actually 255) is considered false
An exit status of 255 (actually 255) is considered false
An exit status of 256 (actually 0) is considered true
An exit status of 257 (actually 1) is considered false
```

Comment: ... more specifically, it's an 8-bit *unsigned* integer.  see http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html for particular meanings.

Comment: @quixotic: Good point; I've edited it in.